# How do I count and even multiple divs child elements with same class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make all "parent" elemens have 5 child elements. If "parent" div has less than 5 childs with class "child", I want to even them all out.

Here's example before:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

This is how result should be:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First select all `.parent` and get content of every of them using `each()`. In loop you can calculating count of element that need to be added. `5 - count of exist child` is count of element that need to be added.

```js
$(".parent").each(function(){
    var count = $(this).children(".child").length;
    for (var i = 0; i < 5 - count; i++){       
        $(this).append("<div class='child'>Added Child</div>");
    }
});
```

```css
.parent {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Child</div>
    <div class="child">Child</div>
    <div class="child">Child</div>
    <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Child</div>
    <div class="child">Child</div>
    <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Child</div>
    <div class="child">Child</div>
    <div class="child">Child</div>
    <div class="child">Child</div>
    <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get maximum count and based on that append additional div

```js
// get maximum count of children in parent
var count = Math.max.apply(Math, $('.parent').map(function() {
    return $('.child', this).length; // get child count
  }).get())
  // if maximum count is fixed then above code can be avoided
  // instead set `count = 5;`

// iterate parent
$('.parent').each(function() {
  var len = count - $('.child', this).length; // get number of div tobe added
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) { // add childrens
    // generate div using jQuery and append it to parent
    $('<div/>', {
      class: 'child'
    }).appendTo(this);
  }
});
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.child {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```